# Are the statements about the correlation coefficient true or false?

Tags: probability, correlation

Let us define the [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) as
$\rho(X,Y) = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$.

Are the following statements true or false?

1. If $\rho(X,Y)=\rho(Y,Z)=0$ then $\rho(X,Z)=0$
2. If $\rho(X,Y)>\rho(Y,Z)>0$ then $\rho(X,Z)>0$
3. If $\rho(X,Y)<\rho(Y,Z)<0$ then $\rho(X,Z)<0$

I think they are false, but I can't find counterexamples. Could you help me?

Comment: but what is $\rho$ ?

Comment: Sorry, is the correlation coefficient

Comment: Can you define the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$ in your post?

Comment: Sure, I've already edited it!

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed all false.  For the first one, you can take $X=Z$ as a counterexample, and have $Y$ be independent of $X$.  For the second, you can take $X$ and $Z$ to be iid $N(0,1)$ random variables and $Y:= X + Z$.  Basically the same counterexample works for the third, but with $Y := -X-Z$ instead.